# Regex rule to match value and replace with specific related value

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

This is primarily a regex question, but it is being used in **Codeigniter's routing file**. The routing file is a list of regex rules that it tries the match. Thus the need for a 1 liner.

Take the following 4 strings:

```
techniques/foo3
news/bar-4-22   
reviews/non23-a
features/wins
```

I'm looking for a 1 line, regex rule that will find techniques,news,reviews or features and replace with a particular int value of 5,1,7 or 3. The number corresponds to the name, so techniques=5, news=1, reviews=7 and features=3. The last value after the slash can be any URL friendly text string. I'll be selecting this as well strait as is. I essentially want to convert them to the following:

```
categorysearch/5/foo3
categorysearch/1/bar-4-22   
categorysearch/7/non23-a
categorysearch/3/wins
```

Can this be done with 1 regex line?

Comment: EH? can you show what you would like your first 4 strings to transform into -> your question is confuzzling!

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I've updated with the results I would like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $route['techniques/(:any)'] = 'categorysearch/5/$1';
 $route['news/(:any)'] = 'categorysearch/1/$1';
```

This will work I would think!

Comment: It's close, but i'm hoping for a 1 liner that will work for all 4 instances. Thus the need to match (techniques|news|reviews|features) to (5|1|7|3)

Comment: But that isn't how routing works I am afraid. The codeigniter routing engine isn't clever enough for anything other than the above.

Comment: However if you are looking to do this you should use a default that routes this through to a standard method -> then anything that isn't picked up will route through your method and you can do the logic in standard PHP there. `$route['default_controller']`

Comment: From what I can tell, it isn't a routing issue, its a regex issue. My knowledge on regex isn't good enough to know if this is even possible with regex. I can write a rule that will match the 4 types, but I can't get it to match to a corresponding integer in 1 routing rule.

Comment: Your problem isnt that you can't write a regex that does this -> the problem is that the $route is not a regex as such but an array that corresponds to a regex -> CI will look for $route['a_route'] and then apply the regex after the equals sign to decide what to do. You can't give CI 4 options on the left hand side of the equation and so can't do what you want. As I said only way is to use a $route['default_controller'] and pipe it to a method that can make the decisions in PHP - or just do as I said above as it will be easier to maintain and sounds like you are just over-complicating things.

Comment: I think you're right. I kind wanted 1 rule to deal with these 4 rules which all essentially go to the same controller with a different variable.

Comment: I tried to do the same at first - I was trying to write a 'one rule for all' - but it meant changing the actual routes.php file in the core - rule of thumb with CI is if you have to touch the core - you are doing it wrong! Don't worry about a few extra lines of code - its how CI is set-up sometimes that means you have to work with what you got! Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) like so:

```
$tokens = [
    'techniques' => 5,
    'news'       => 1,
    'reviews'    => 7,
    'features'   => 3
];

echo preg_replace_callback('#^([^/]+)/(.*)$#', function ($m) use ($tokens) {
    if (array_key_exists($m[1], $tokens)) {
        return sprintf('%s/%d/%s', $m[1], $tokens[$m[1]], $m[2]);
    }
    return sprintf('%s/%s', $m[1], $m[2]);
}, $string);
```

If the replacement is simple as this, a regex is not even required. A simple [`sscanf()`](http://php.net/sscanf) or [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) (with the [`list`](http://php.net/list) construct) should suffice.

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/7S4qgi)

Comment: excellent answer - BUT why encourage a regex - a simple string replace would do the job with 70% less server load! +1 anyway.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie: Indeed. You're right. But the OP wanted to use a regex, so I just wanted to show him an example. I've updated my answer to include some alternative approaches!

Comment: i have added to favourites list as I hadn't thought of doing it this way for array of replacements with regexes -> I would have used | between multiple statements like a noob (although technically would have been one line!)

Comment: @GrahamRitchie: The problem with `if` statements involving multiple conditions is that you'll never be able to tell which condition was met. If the number of `if` statements are too high, perhaps you could use a `switch` block as well. And here's a [**regex-free solution**](http://ideone.com/KmINyi) using `explode()` :-)

Comment: @AmalMurali Thanks for the answer, however I really need something that is a 1 line, regex match. This is being used in Codeigniter's routing file which is a list of regex rules to match.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a regex for everything - they are not efficient for simple things like this and are designed for more complex scenarios.

The following will do the job (there are better ways but this is easiest to follow!)

```
$rawstring = "techniques/foo3"

$find = array('techniques', 'news', 'reviews', 'features');
$replace = array('5', '1', '7', '3');

$return = str_replace($find, "categorysearch/" . $replace, $rawstring);

//$return = "categorysearch/5/foo3"
```

This way also works and is simple to follow for noobies like me :-P Amals answer is far superior!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I really need something that is a 1 line, regex match. This is being used in Codeigniter's routing file which is a list of regex rules to match.

Comment: Wait till the value is something like `messagepreviews/foobar` or `renews/foobar`. This approach is good enough if you don't care about the cases where the search term could occur *inside* the string.

Comment: valid point! wasn't thinking it through to fruition - easy to fix but not going to bother as OP has stated neither are suitable. Actually need a routing option for him.